# Can't validate Anti-Forgery token,getting error 400

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, antiforgerytoken

I want to implement an anti-forgery token in my software.The problem is that i am doing it outside of a form.

here is my program.cs

```
{
    options.FormFieldName = "AntiforgeryFieldname";
    options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyAntiForgeryCookie";
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
}); 


builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

here is my controller

```
[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
[Route("api/appointment/public")]
[Authorize(Policy = Permissions.Appointments.MakeAppointments)]
```

and here is my js

```
   function create(successCallback) {
       let model = {
           client: appointmentClientService.data.client,
           address: appointmentClientService.data.address,
           animals: appointmentAnimalService.animals,
           deposit: vm.deposit
       };

       Object.assign(model, appointmentData);

       // Retrieve anti-forgery token from the cookie
       const antiForgeryCookie = getAntiForgeryCookie('MyAntiForgeryCookie');
       console.log(antiForgeryCookie); 
       // Include anti-forgery token in the request headers
       const headers = {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': antiForgeryCookie
       };
       console.log(headers);
       vm.requestPending = true;
       $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: '/api/appointment/public',
           data: model,
           headers: headers
       })
           .then(function (response) {
               toastr.success('Appointment created.');
               clearWindowUnloadCheck();

               printPaperwork(response.data.ids, function () {
                   successCallback(response.data);
               });
           })
           .catch(function (response) {
               clinichq.helpers.showErrorMessage(response);
               vm.requestPending = false;
           });
   }

   function getAntiForgeryCookie(cookieName) {
       const cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
       const antiForgeryCookie = cookies.find(row => row.startsWith(`${cookieName}=`));

       if (antiForgeryCookie) {
           return antiForgeryCookie.split('=')[1];
       }

       return null;
   }
```

[image]

the photo is from my headers

and also here is another picture from my cookies
[image]

In my console logs i see the correct cookie but I don't know how to validated it.

Comment: The cookie is in the response of the HTTP request.

Comment: And where should it be?

Comment: It is in the HTTP header in the response.

Comment: can you update my code because I can't figure it out,I am sorry

Comment: You need to get it from your variable "response".  The cookies are different in the request and the response.  You need to get the cookie by the header name in the response.

Comment: It's my first time doing this can you pleas show me how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256411/discussion-between-fico-and-jdweng).